# NH2- and Primary Alkyl Halides: Sn2 vs E2

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

When we mix 1-bromopropane and $\ce{NaNH2}$, what happens? Which reactions wins out to make the major product?

My textbook says that primary alkyl halides give mainly SN2 products unless the base is hindered ($\ce{t-BuO-}$) (where E2 would win out).

But it contradicts itself when you have for example 1,2-dichlorobutane and you add three molar equivalents of $\ce{NaNH2}$ and then $\ce{NH4Cl}$ to have an alkyne. Why is there no SN2 going on in that case?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, Sodamide is generally insoluble, except in liquid ammonia.  And why do people like to prepare amines with ammonia as a nucleophile?  The basicity complicates things, as does the fact that the primary amine initially formed will react further to give secondary and tertiary amines, even quaternary ammonium compounds.  It's not a reaction useful in preparative chemistry.

That said, the balance of nucleophilicity and basicity is also influenced by the solvent.  It's well known that KO*t*-Bu acts mostly as a base in THF and mostly as a nucleophile in DMSO, there's plenty of examples in the literature.  Hydrogen-bonding solvents tip the balance towards elimination.

Comment: So, that means that the major product will be the alkyne because the immensely great basicity of NH2- will win out even though there could be some NH2- that could do Sn2?

Comment: My gut feeling is that from 1-bromopropane and NaNH2 in liquid ammonia you'd get mostly propene.